# get all instances of a class in python

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, instance

This is my class in the file `files.py`:

```
class Files():

    def __init__(self, *, kwargs1=None, ......, kwargsx=None):
        self.kwargs1 = kwargs1
        ...................
        ...................
        ...................
        self.kwargsx = kwargsx

        __validate()
        if self.kwargs1 == "create":
            self.__create()
        if kwargsx == "remove":
            self.__remove()

    def __validate():
        validate attributes of object and raise execption if fails

    def __create(self):
        create file

    def __remove(self):
        remove file
```

In another file `tasks.py` I have this:

```
from files import File

File(kwargs1="create", kwargs2="path/to/destination1", kwargs3="/path/to/source1",..........)
File(kwargs1="create", kwargs2="path/to/destination2", kwargs3="/path/to/source2",..........)
```

The current situation is that each object is getting validated and then proceed with `__create()` or `__remove()`. What I was asking is if it is possible to validate all objects first and then proceed.
I could achieve it in the `tasks.py`. I had to declare the private methods `__create()` and `__remove()` as public methods `create(self)` and `remove(self)` and the class looks like this:

```
class Files():

    def __init__(self, *, kwargs1=None, ......, kwargsx=None):
        self.kwargs1 = kwargs1
        ...................
        ...................
        ...................
        self.kwargsx = kwargsx

        __validate()

    def __validate():
        validate attributes of object and raise execption if fails

    def create(self):
        create file

    def remove(self):
        remove file
```

And the `tasks.py`:

```
files = []
try:
    files.append(File(kwargs1="create", kwargs2="path/to/destination1", kwargs3="/path/to/source1",..........))
    files.append(File(kwargs1="create", kwargs2="path/to/destination2", kwargs3="/path/to/source2",..........))
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
else:
    for item in files:
        if item.kwargsx == "create":
            create(item)
        elif item.kwargsx == "remove":
            remove(item)
```

My question is if it is possible to implement this logic in the class File itself? The only way I could think of is a work around with inspecting the stack and iterate over each object initialization, but I don't know if it would work!

Answer (score 0):

This is a general scheme - a class does not have reference to instances,

```
class File:
    _instances = []
    def __init__(self, ..., action=None):
        ....
        self.action = action
        File._instances.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def resolve_actions(cls):
        for instance in cls._instances:
            if instance.action == "create":
                instance.__create()
            elif instance.action == "remove":
                instance.__remove()
```

and then somewhere in the code

```
File.resolve_actions()
```

Comment: I have achieved validating the attributes of the object one by one, so for instance if all OK with the first instance it gets created, and the same for the second object. I am trying to get all of the objects checking them one by one and only then do the action for each, or get the first object, validate and store it, get the second, validate and store, if all pass then proceed with the appropriate action for each object! Is such a scenario possible?

Comment: @Max, I provided you with a general scheme. In a loop you can accumulate results and act on them in a second loop - or you may set it as another class attribute and accumulate your decision with each instance creation, and then again execute it once over all instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think I did not point my question clearly or I just do not understand how to do it. Any way I'll edit the question.